# Problems on Encode/Decode UIImage in base64 uploading/downloading

Tags: swift, base64, decode, encode

I'm working in a project with PHP backend and an Swift app where, in backend I upload an image and then, from Swift app I download it. In the Swift app I have the possibility to upload image, remove the old image in the backend and save the new, similar to the facebook profile picture.

Right now, I take the base64 string from the API of backend, I convert to UIImage and it works with this code:

```
let data: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: "string from API", options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

var img: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

When I take a photo in Swift app, from Gallery or from cam, I try to encode the image and upload with the API. The first thing I don't understand is why when I codified the image, the length of the String generated is the double, more or less, of the String from API when I take the image from the backend.

I try to download the image from the backend and upload the same image to see if the string generated in base64 is the same, but not.

This is what I make for encode the image form Swift app:

```
let img: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MyImage.image, 1.0)!

let base64Image: String = img.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

In PHP I use base64_encode(string) but the file generated is damaged or illegible.